# How do I upload an image to a certain Picasa Web album without using the deprecated API?

Tags: api, picasa

It says so on https://developers.google.com/picasa/ that the APIs are deprecated. Is there a way to upload an image to a specified album and get the URL of the uploaded image?

The reason why I didn't specify the language is because I'm looking for a solution that can be done in most languages. If you will ask me to choose a specific one, I might go for AS3.

Answer (score 0):

Picasa in and of itself seems to be a dying product, as Google+ is taking over more and more. So, your best bet would just be to use Google+, and, if that's not possible, just go with the deprecated API.